# Verify Errors implementing method proxy using ASM byte code modification library

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am having difficulties using the ASM byte code library to create proxy methods.

I wish to convert the following code:

```
public ReturnType doSomething( ParameterOne parameterOne, 
    ParameterTwo parameterTwo ){

    ReturnType returnType = new ReturnType();
    returnType.setDataOne( parameterOne.getDataOne() );
    returnType.setDataTwo( parameterTwo.getDataTwo() );
    return returnType;
}
```

to:

```
public ReturnType copyOff_doSomething( ParameterOne parameterOne, 
    ParameterTwo parameterTwo ){

    ReturnType returnType = new ReturnType();
    returnType.setDataOne( parameterOne.getDataOne() );
    returnType.setDataTwo( parameterTwo.getDataTwo() );
    return returnType;
}

public ReturnType doSomething( ParameterOne parameterOne, 
    ParameterTwo parameterTwo ){

    return copyOff_doSomething( parameterOne, parameterTwo );
}
```

To create the copyOff_doSomething() method I am using the following code:

```
public MethodVisitor visitMethod( int access, String name, String desc, 
    String signature, String[] exceptions ) {

    System.out.println(
        "access= " + access + ", name = " + name + ", desc = " +
                  desc + ", signature = " + signature );

    if ( name.equals( "doSomething" ) ){

        MethodVisitor methodVisitor =
            super.visitMethod( access, "copyOff_" + name, desc, 
                signature, exceptions );

        return methodVisitor;
    }
    else {
        return super.visitMethod( access, name, desc, signature, exceptions );
    }
}
```

The above code effectively removes the original doSomething() method and copies it to copyOff_doSomething() along with its body of code.

My problem occurs when I am generating the replacement doSomething() method:

```
@Override
public void visitEnd() {

    MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod( ACC_PUBLIC, "doSomething", 
        "(Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterOne;" + 
        "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterTwo;)" + 
        "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ReturnType;", 
            null, null );

    mv.visitCode();
    Label l0 = new Label();
    mv.visitLabel( l0 );
    mv.visitLineNumber( 18, l0 );
    mv.visitVarInsn( ALOAD, 0 );
    mv.visitVarInsn( ALOAD, 1 );
    mv.visitVarInsn( ALOAD, 2 );

    mv.visitMethodInsn( INVOKEVIRTUAL, 
        "com/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/FinalMethod", 
           "copyOff_doSomething", 
               "(Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterOne;" +        
               "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterTwo;)" + 
               "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ReturnType;");

    mv.visitInsn( ARETURN );
    Label l1 = new Label();
    mv.visitLabel( l1 );

    mv.visitLocalVariable( "this", 
       "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/FinalMethod;", 
           null, l0, l1, 0 );

    mv.visitLocalVariable( "parameterOne", 
        "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterOne;", 
            null, l0, l1, 1 );

    mv.visitLocalVariable( "parameterTwo", 
        "Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterTwo;", 
            null, l0, l1, 2 );

    mv.visitMaxs( 3, 3 );
    mv.visitEnd();
    super.visitEnd();
}
```

The problem is I get the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in method 
com.javaspeak.classloader.tests.proxymethod.ProxyMethod.doSomething(
Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterOne;
Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ParameterTwo;)
Lcom/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/ReturnType; at offset 3
```

I do not know what the error means and how to fix the error.  As mentioned above I used ASMfier to generate the code for the replacement doSomething() method.

My strategy was to use the visitMethod method to rename doSomething() to copyOff_doSomething() and then use the visitEnd() method to generate a new replacement doSomething() method from scratch that calls the copyOff_doSomething() method.

Perhaps ASM does not cater for my strategy and I should do it a different way?

Perhaps I need to modify the code that the ASMfier generated for the replacement doSomething() method. My understanding of the generated code is not that good.

I am using JDK 1.7 and ASM 4.0. I used ASMfier to see what ASM byte code instructions to use to generate the replacement doSomething() method.

If anyone knows ASM your help will be much appreciated?

Cheers

John

Comment: disassemble the code of `doSomething` and see what is at offset 3. Most likely, there is `invokevirtual` instruction. Check if it is feed with correct arguments.

Comment: In response to Alexei, how does one disassemble the code?  Do you have a link on how to do the disassemble?

Comment: javap -c java.class.name.to.decode - javap is a tool from JDK. Other disassemblers exist - https://www.google.ru/search?q=java+disassembler

Comment: this is addressed in the FAQ on ASM:: "4. Why do I get the [xxx] verifier error?" http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q4 this should be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Alexei and Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the `owner` parameter (hardcoded to `com/javaspeak/classloader/tests/proxymethod/FinalMethod` in your example) don't match the actual type for `this`. So, your adapter should be using the `name` value from `ClassVisitor.visit(..)` call.

Also see "Replace Method Body" section in my [AOSD'07](http://asm.ow2.org/current/asm-transformations.pdf) paper "Using ASM framework to implement common bytecode transformation patterns".

Comment: Thanks Eugene, your answer was very helpful.  I changed the name FinalMethod to ProxyMethod and it worked.  Much appreciated.  Thank you.